# How to get acces to a property from other form?

Tags: c#

i need to get acces to this properties :

```
     public string TipoDocumento { get; set; }
     public int NumeroDocumento { get; set; }
```

these properties are located in a class called Profesores , and i have another class called  AltaActividadesProfesores in which I have a stored procedure that uses them and have no idea how to obtain.

Comment: You need to pass an instance of your class to the other code.

Comment: Or better yet, use an MVC model.  Not at all common for WinForms, but certainly can be done, e.g.: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613682/Your-first-program-using-MVC-pattern-with-Csharp-W

Answer (score 0):

You need a Professores instance in order to access those properties outside of the class (or any derived classes).

You can create an instance using the **new** operator, as such:

```
var professorObject = new Professorers();
```

Then you can access the properties:

```
professorObject .TipoDocumento = ...
```

If you would like to access them without an instance, then declare them static, as such:

```
 public static string TipoDocumento { get; set; }
 public static int NumeroDocumento { get; set; }
```

Then you can access them from anywhere like this:

```
Professores.TipoDocumento = ...
```

Keep in mind that static properties are not associated with any instance. More information on static members can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Comment: Declaring them as static has a very different meaning than using a form instance.  The advice is misleading by not explaining the significance of that choice.  He most likely needs to get the value from a *specific instance*, which you do not address with either solution.

Comment: Edited to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

I have a  constructor who has all the parameters that need , should use that constructor or create a new one which will not pass any parameters ?

Another thing , do what you said , but I think that expresses me wrong before, I need to know how to pass these values ​​to reference them because I have this stored procedure :

```
private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvActivProfe.Items)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source = USUARIO-PC; initial catalog = BaseDeDatosGimnasio; integrated security=True ");
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Actividades/Profesor](NumeroDocumentoProfesor,TipoDocumentoProfesor,CodigoActividad,Dia,HoraDesde,HoraHasta) values ('" + numeroDocProfe + "','" + tipoDocProfe + "','" + item.SubItems[i].Text + "','" + lblLunes + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(comboBoxHDLunes.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(comboBoxHHLunes.Text) + "')", con);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

As you will see I have as primary key type and number of document , and I need those values ​​to upload with this stored procedure.

Im working with a proyect of three layers , i have in the business layer the class called profesores and in the presentation layer the class called AltaActividadesProfesor.